# How to handle multiple calls of the same request in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The app has the filter page which contains many filters. Every filter widget returns the selected arguments and then, the funtion ***_getFilters()*** is called, in the filters page, in order to update all the filters values.

But the issue is that when the user selects many widgets quickly, there are a number of requests of ***_getFilters()*** function, so the state changes based on every request, until to end the requests.
Below there is a video for better understanding.
[Video with the issue](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WCBv8tBP2K5bLoUpKj7h71gyTSeudb1/view?usp=sharing)

Is there any idea how to fix-improve this?

**filters_page.dart**

```
  Future<void> _getFilters() async {
    Debouncer(milliseconds: 700).run(() async {

      setState(() {
        isLoading = true;
      });   
       
      final response = await SearchService.searchClassifieds(params);         
      searchResult = response;
      
      isLoading = false;
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    });
  }
```

**slider_filter_widget.dart**

```
class SliderFilter extends StatefulWidget {
  const SliderFilter({
    Key? key,
    this.facet,
    required this.onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Facets? facet;
  final ValueChanged<Map<String, String>> onChanged;

  @override
  State<SliderFilter> createState() => _SliderFilterState();
}

class _SliderFilterState extends State<SliderFilter> {
  late RangeValues selectedRange;

  Map<String, String> args = {};

  bool canEnd = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeValues();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant SliderFilter oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (oldWidget.facet != widget.facet) {
      initializeValues();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RangeSlider(
          values: selectedRange,
          onChanged: (val) {
            canEnd = true;
            selectedRange = val;
            setState(() {});
          },
          onChangeEnd: (values) {         
            if (canEnd) {
              args.addAll({"start": values.start, "end":values.end,},),\
              // Return the selected arguments
              widget.onChanged(args);
            }
          },        
          min: 0,
          max: (list.length - 1).toDouble(),
          divisions: list.length - 1,
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the state of each of the filters in the parent and by tapping the show button call the route with all filters.

Comment: If you want to act on only the final one, then you need "debounce" logic on a stream somewhere.  There are a few solutions in the pub for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your future to a Stream

```
SearchService.searchClassifieds(params).asStream().listen((result){};
```

Create a StreamSubscription variable inside your class

```
StreamSubscription? streamSubscription;
```

Assign the stream to the StreamSubscription:

```
streamSubscription =  SearchService.searchClassifieds(params).asStream().listen((result){ your logic here ...};
```

Before you make another call you cancel your current stream subscription:

```
streamSubscription?.cancel();
```